# Does perfect brevity always flow?

Tags: style

Most of the style guides say to make every sentence as concise as possible. But does this kind of writing always flow? Don't you sometimes need to add to a sentence an extra word or two in order to make it flow?

Comment: You are quite right. Be ruthless but be selective. I'd go with *I don't absolutely need that term, but I am attached to it for what it adds*.

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely, yes.
In fact, vary your sentence length.
Too many short sentences becomes as difficult to read as too many long, flowing sentences.
Variety is the spice of life they say, and variety in sentence length is the spice that makes any work a joy to read, rather than a chore.